# Make the x labels different from the legend in plotly with go.Box

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I add multiple `go.Box()` in my figure, and I want the x axis labels to be different from the legend. How can I do that?

[image: Plotly boxplot]

More precisely:

- I would like the x labels to be: "device field strength 1.5", "device field strength 3" and "device model changed",
- I want only 2 legend labels: "F1 score" and "Dice score".

**Details & context**

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
    method  group   patient device_field_strength   variable    value
0   expert1 experts 62  device_field_strength_1.5   F1_score    0.857
1   expert1 experts 66  device_field_strength_3     F1_score    0.909
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

and the following code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = go.Figure()

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=("4 experts", "4 methods with highest F1 score"))

device_field_strengths = device_field_strength_impact_df.device_field_strength.unique()

for group in ['experts', 'best_methods']:
    for metric in ['F1_score', 'Dice']:
        for device_field_strength in device_field_strengths:
            fig.add_trace(go.Box(
                y=device_field_strength_impact_df[(device_field_strength_impact_df.device_field_strength==device_field_strength) & (device_field_strength_impact_df.group==group) & (device_field_strength_impact_df.variable==metric)].value,
                name=f'{device_field_strength} {metric}',
                text=group,
                legendgroup=metric,
                marker_color='darkblue' if metric == 'F1_score' else 'red',
                boxmean=True # represent mean
            ), row=1, col=1 if group == 'experts' else 2)


fig.show()
```

Note: I made [the same figure with Plotly express but I think it cannot show the mean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76216700/719276).

Update: [r-beginners](https://community.plotly.com/u/r-beginners) explained me how to add the mean with plotly express: just add  `fig.update_traces(boxmean=True)` after the `px.box()`! Thanks r-beginners :)