# Add the mean in box plots with plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot, plotly-python, plotly-express

I have the following figure:

[image: Box plot from plotly express]

and I would like to add the mean.

Is it possible with Plotly Express, without using Graph Objects `go.Box()`?

For information, here is my code:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.box(device_field_strength_impact_df, 
        y='value',
        x='device_field_strength', 
        color='variable', 
        # boxmean=True,
        facet_col='group',
        )
fig.show()
```

and the pandas DataFrame:

```
method  group   patient device_field_strength   variable    value
expert1 experts 62  device_field_strength_1.5   F1_score    0.857
expert1 experts 66  device_field_strength_3     F1_score    0.909
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Note: I made [the same figure with Graph Objects but I don't know how to handle the legend and x labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76216656/719276).

Comment: You can add the averages by adding, after the graph, the settings for the averages you have already tried. `... ; fig.update_traces(boxmean=True);fig.show()`

Answer (score 3):

As @r-beginners answered in his comment:

> You can add the averages by adding `fig.update_traces(boxmean=True)` after the `px.box()`.

Indeed, the following code works perfectly:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.box(device_field_strength_impact_df, 
        y='value',
        x='device_field_strength', 
        color='variable', 
        facet_col='group',
        )
fig.update_traces(boxmean=True)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create empty plot and then set parameters for boxplot using `fig.update_traces`, including mean:

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.box()

fig.update_traces(
    # box
    q1=[1, 2, 3], 
    median=[4, 5, 6],
    q3=[7, 8, 9], 
    # fences
    lowerfence=[-1, 0, 1],
    upperfence=[10, 11, 12], 
    # mean and std
    mean=[2.2, 2.8, 4.2],
    sd=[0.2, 0.4, 0.6], 
    notchspan=[0.2, 0.4, 0.6],
    
    boxpoints=False
)

fig.show()
```

Not the most convenient method (you have to calculate values separately), but looks like it works.

Comment: would that be a question you could contribute? I am trying to implement the ```lowerfence``` and ```upperfence``` unsuccessfully -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78106793/how-to-group-data-and-also-specify-the-percentiles-in-a-go-box